# display x amount of two Randomize arrays and output the same “randomized” result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How would I take two arrays and with 20 elements each and display 5 at random. not the first 5 but 5 random ones. this is a drag and drop acitiby that I want to be able to redo hence the randomized selection.

I tried using something like  `match1.length = match1.length < 5 ? match1.length : 5;` and it kinda worked but it would display the 5 correct one and the rest would show up as null blank spaces

```
var match1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",  "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]; 


//this are drop target (#rightCol)
var match2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",  "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"];
```

This is what I am using to randomize the arrays

```
var i=0, len= match1.length, next, order=[];
while(i<len)order[i]= ++i;
order.sort(function(){return Math.random()+.5});

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    next=order[i];
    match1.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match1[next]);
    match2.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match2[next]);
}
match1.splice(1, len);
match2.splice(1, len);
```

but it display all 20 at once and I only want 5 at a time so it can be redone multiply times.

This is the rest of the code.

```
  //shuffle the arrays
  arrMatch1 = shuffle(match1);
  arrMatch2 = shuffle(match2);

  //insert them into DOM
  $('#source').html(match1.join(''));
  $('#target').html(match2.join(''));
}




function shuffle(v) {
  for(var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);

  return v;
}




function initQuiz() {
  $('#source li').draggable(
  {
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 600,
    cursor: "all-scroll"
  });

 var    totalScore  =   0;
$('#score').text(totalScore +   '   correct answer');
$('#target  li').droppable(
{
        accept  :   function(draggable)
        {
                if(parseInt(draggable.data('index'),    10) === 
parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10))
                {
                        return  true;
                }
                else
                {
                        return  false;
                }
        },
        drop:   function(   event,  ui  )   
        {
                var that    =   $(this);
                that.addClass(  "ui-state-highlight").html('Correct!');
                that.droppable('disable');
                ui.draggable.addClass('correct  ui-state-active');
                (ui.draggable).draggable('disable');
                totalScore++;
                $('#score').text(totalScore +   '   matching answer');
                if($('li.correct').length   ==  10)
                {
                        $(  "#dialog-complete"  ).dialog({
                                resizable:  false,
                                modal:  true
                        });
                }
        }
});

}
```

Comment: Do you want those 5 removed from the array or just selected?

Comment: `return Math.random()+.5}`  your sort function is always going to return `>0`..   I think what you was after was -> `return Math.random()-.5}`

Comment: 5 selected from the array